# TypeError: $(...)[1].attr is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have links set up like so:

**HTML:**

```
<a href="www.example1.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example2.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example3.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
```

I want to get the `href`s that the `<a>` tags contain. I tried to iterate through each link like so:

**Javascript / jQuery:**

```
for (x=0; x < 5; x++) {
  link = $(".some-link")[x].attr("href");
  console.log(link);
}
```

When I try this, I get the error `TypeError: $(...)[x].attr is not a function`. What's the issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use **[`eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** here, since `$(".some-link")[x]` returns dom object **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr)** method can only use with jQuery object. So you nee to use **[`eq(x)`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)** or **[`:eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)**

```js
for (x=0; x < 5; x++) {
   link = $(".some-link").eq(x).attr("href");
   console.log(link);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.example1.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example2.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example3.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
```

or you can use **[`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each)** method instead

```js
$(".some-link").each(function(){
   var link=$(this).attr("href");
   console.log(link);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.example1.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example2.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example3.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
```

or more simple way use **[`attr()`](https://api.jquery.com/attr)** with callback

```js
$(".some-link").attr("href",function(i,link){
   console.log(link);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="www.example1.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example2.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example3.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
<a href="www.example4.com" class="some-link">
```

Answer (score 4):

The `[1]` indexer (equivalent to `.get()`) does not return a jQuery element, but a DOM element. Try

```
var link = $(".some-link").eq(x).attr("href");
```

As a side note, you probably want to declare your variable using `var`.